# How do I reference a Dockerfile in a folder when creating an Azure Container Registry Task?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-registry

I am trying to setup an Azure Container Registry (ACR) to automatically build Docker images when I commit changes to my Git repository.

The problem I'm having is that my Dockerfile is in a folder within the respository. This works, in that Azure retrieves the source code and starts to build the Docker image. However, the Dockerfile refers to files relative to the location of the Dockerfile (i.e. inside the folder). When the ACR Task tries to build the image, it complains that the files can't be found. I suspect it's because it's looking for them in the root of the repository, not in the same folder as the Dockerfile.

Here's how I created the Task:

```
az acr task create -n MyName -r MyRegistry -c https://mySourceRepository -f MyFolder/Dockerfile -t myimage:{{.Run.ID}} --git-access-token <removed>
```

The first portion of the Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM node:12.16.1-alpine AS build

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
```

And the ACR log says this...

```
Status: Downloaded newer image for node:12.16.1-alpine
 ---> f77abbe89ac1
Step 2/9 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Running in 22b362ab217c
Removing intermediate container 22b362ab217c
 ---> ee3d0930d0e9
Step 3/9 : COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder883638973/package.json: no such file or directory
```

Is there a way to specify a 'working folder' within the source repository for the ACR Task?

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this was to specify the folder to use as part of the Context parameter:

```
az acr task create -n MyName -r MyRegistry -c https://mySourceRepository#:MyFolder -f Dockerfile -t myimage:{{.Run.ID}} --git-access-token <removed>
```

This causes the Docker Build operation to start in the specified folder, so the Dockerfile can find the files to which it refers.

See here for [details of Docker Build Contexts](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#git-repositories).

Answer (score 0):

For this issue, you can first take a look at the context of the [`docker build`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/). As it shows, I recommend you make some changes to the Dockerfile. The best way is to put the Dockerfile in the root folder of the repository, and then copy files in the Dockerfile with a relative path according to the root folder.

Of course, you can keep the current directory structure, then you need to change the `COPY` path relate to your Git repository root folder.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I didn't want to move the Dockerfile to the root of the solution as there will be many sub-projects, each with its own Dockerfile. I also didn't want to adjust the Dockerfile to use paths which weren't consistent with the location of the Dockerfile itself. As you say, though - the Docker Context was the key, I used the form myrepo.git#:myfolder to set the specific 'working folder' for the build and all was well!

Comment: @ChrisRoberts Of course, you can select the way you want. But didn't you get the solution from my answer? Why not accept it instead of post another answer that copies from the article I provided.

Comment: As I explained in my comment - your answer pointed me in the right direction, but provided two work-arounds and not the actual solution. So - I thank you for your efforts, but for the benefit of anyone else who runs into the same problem, I posted the specific answer to the problem.

Comment: @ChrisRoberts You always have the reasons!